# MaterialDesignXaml dialog from Caliburn.Micro View Model

Tags: caliburn.micro, material-design-in-xaml

I'm having a problem with showing Dialogs from a View Model.  The problem is that the "underlying content is not dimmed and disabled" as the documentation says it should be.  If I click on the underlying view the button in the dialog wired to the closed command is sometimes disabled and the user is not able to click it.

I defined the DialogHost in my MainView like this (also tried it in the ShellView):

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        CloseOnClickAway="True" />
```

From my MainViewModel I show the dialog like this:

```
   Dim errView As New ErrorView
   Dim res = Await DialogHost.Show(errView)
```

I wired up the close command on a button in the ErrorView dialog like this:

```
Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is with the definition of DialogHost; you have it as an empty element.

The DialogHost is a ContentControl.  Everything inside is what will become dimmed.  So you define it at the root of your *main* Window/Page XAML, a bit more like:

```
<materialDesign:DialogHost CloseOnClickAway="True">
  <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock>Hello World</TextBlock>
    <TextBlock>This is the main content of my application</TextBlock>
  </StackPanel>
</materialDesign:DialogHost>
```

Comment: Geez so simple... thanks for the help.  I haven't noticed the issue with the close button being disabled. Is it somehow related?

Comment: Probably yes, the static close command is  RoutedCommand, so it is bubbling up, looking for a DialogHost to execute on.